# Why Isn't my custom entity shooting fireballs? (Minecraft Bedrock Addon Making)

Tags: json, minecraft

I'm fairly new in making addons for Minecraft Bedrock, and right now I'm trying to make an addon that adds the "Wildfire" mob from the Minecon votes. And I basically got everything right I got the model, the animations and the melee attack. But, for some reason the "Wildfire" won't shoot the "fireballs" I basically copied the code from the vanilla Minecraft entity Blaze code. I've searched everywhere but no luck since theres not much topics/q&a on Minecraft Bedrock. I have no idea why this won't work. Please help me, thanks in advance!

```
     "mode_switcher": {
       "minecraft:target_nearby_sensor": {
         "inside_range": 2.0,
         "outside_range": 3.0,
         "must_see": true,
         "on_inside_range": {
           "event": "switch_to_melee",
           "target": "self"
         },
         "on_outside_range": {
           "event": "switch_to_ranged",
           "target": "self"
         }
       }
     },

     "ranged_mode": {
       "minecraft:behavior.ranged_attack": {
         "priority": 3,
         "burst_shots": 3,
         "burst_interval": 0.3,
         "charge_charged_trigger": 0.0,
         "charge_shoot_trigger": 4.0,
         "attack_interval_min": 3.0,
         "attack_interval_max": 5.0,
         "attack_radius": 16.0
       },

       "minecraft:shooter": {
         "def": "minecraft_small_fireball"
       }

     },

     "events": {

     "minecraft:entity_spawned": {
       "add": {
         "component_groups": [
           "mode_switcher"
         ]
       }
     },
     "switch_to_melee": {
       "remove": {
         "component_groups": [
           "ranged_mode"
         ]
       },
       "add": {
         "component_groups": [
           "melee_mode"
         ]
       }
     },
     "switch_to_ranged": {
       "remove": {
         "component_groups": [
           "melee_mode"
         ]
       },
       "add": {
         "component_groups": [
           "ranged_mode"
         ]
       }
     },
     "minecraft:on_hurt_event": {
       "add": {
         "component_groups": [
           "mode_switcher"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
```

This is not all the code Its just the code that's related to it. Please tell me if you want all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. Well I guess not solve it because im still not to sure on what the problem was but, what I did was I used the code from the blaze in the Minecraft Beta version. That fixed it the only difference I found was that in the "ranged_mode" the "minecraft:shooter" component was before the "minecraft:behavior_ranged_attack".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may have been mixing code from multiple format versions like I did before I realized that there was a difference. It could also be possible that you didn't make its attack range large enough, I also didn't see any code that selects a target for it to target. For any attacks to work you will need to make it select a target first. It look like you have only included code that allows it to swap attack types for a selected target. Keep this in mind when making behaviors in the future.